# Remove parameter from URL viac .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I need advice how to remove a parameter from the url using. Htcaccess

The condition is as follows:

redirect url from:

`http://example.com/?movie=2&ref=nf`

to:

`http://example.com/?movie=2`

I tried several options but I have not come to nothing

Thank you for your ideas / advice.

THX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following to the `.htaccess` file in the root directory of your site.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase / 

#If request contains ref param
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?([^&\ ]+)&ref=  [NC]  
#redirect to URL without the ref param
RewriteRule ^  %{REQUEST_URI}?%1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: I got an answer form server Internal Server Error 500.

Comment: @JozífekChramršt Sorry - I had a typo, try above now